ubuntu routing for vpn client
I'm new to network programming and I'm trying to create my vpn using this code I created tun interface
   import pytun as pt 
   tun=pt.TunTapDevice(name='mytun')
   tun.addr='10.0.0.1'
   tun.dstaddr='10.0.0.2'
   tun.mtu = 1500
   tun.up()
   while 1:
       data= tun.read(tun.mtu)


My vpn client is supposed to create a virtual interface and ALL programs should listen to it, then after the bytes are read by my tun interface they are sent to the program which sockets them to the server.
So I need to route all applications on my pc to listen to my mytun virtual network interface but I can send bytes (packets) through my real network card, I tried using ip route add 10.0.0.2 via 10.0.0.1 but it didn't work (I must have tried it wrong).

The language on AU i English. Please translate your question.

@SorenAI added my question in English

The question is not related to Ubuntu, it is a programming / Python question. You may want to consider raising the question at Stack Overflow, which is a forum dedicated to programming questions.

@Noisefloor I'm asking about routing on Ubuntu, I provided the code so that there would be a clear idea
